# Android how to show 50% transparent of a non-selected image in a gallery view? (selected will be 100%)

Tags: android

Android how to show 50% transparent of a non-selected image in a 
gallery view? (selected will be 100%)

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you want to achieve?

Comment: You need to override the gallery view and set alpha of all the images to 50% initially and whenever one gets selected you need to make alpha 100%

Comment: How can i check it what is the selected image in the gallery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i figured it out:

Works fine when u add this, to your gallery:

```
style="android:galleryItemBackground"
```

so the code:

```
   <Gallery style="android:galleryItemBackground"
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top" android:layout_marginTop="50dip"/>
```

and then

```
gallery.setUnselectedAlpha(0.3f);
```

then on getview:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

    position= getPosition(position); 

    i.setImageBitmap(images.elementAt(position));
    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

    i.setBackgroundColor(R.color.chatblue); //add some background, and it work! 


    return i;
}
```